# Installation of Windows Cloudera ODBC Hive Driver does not show Driver in odbcad32

Tags: windows, odbc, hive, cloudera, tableau-api

I downloaded and installed cloudera odbc hive drivers provided in the link https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/con/Cloudera+Connector+for+Tableau. But when running odbcad32.exe (ODBC Data Source Administrator) the Drivers tab does not show anything new related to this driver. I have tried it on Window Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7. Anyone experiencing the same and do have a solution?
Thanks, Cees

Comment: Was the driver installed using the Administrator account? If so (and it's going to sound silly), have you tried restarting the computer?

Comment: Hi, I ran the installation with right-click Run As Administrator. After reboot the driver is still not listed.

Comment: If there is still an issue with installing the Cloudera driver, then I would recommend contacting Cloudera technical support for more assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of the ODBC manager are you using?  If your platform is 64-bit, the Cloudera ODBC driver will not show up using the 64-bit manager (the Driver is 32-bit). Therefore, you must use the 32-bit manager which can be found under c:/windows/sysWoW64/odbcad32.exe.

Keep in mind that the 32-bit adapter can only be used with 32-bit applications.

Hope this is helpful.